# Dispatching two sync actions

Tags: redux

My use case comprises of dispatching two actions from a recursive function (if else construct ) the if part which adds a row in an array ( which is a state of my app) and the else part adds another row and needs to access the length of the array before  and call the function itself. What I see here is the length of the array remains same after the first action is being dispatched and thus the call to itself doesn't get the actual value of the length .

Comment: provide more information such as the code and errors

Comment: Can you refer to the comment I added for ageoff ..I wrote something just like that can't post the exact thing as it is something proprietory.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is you are trying to do the second check/call after the first within the component. The component must wait for the new props on the next render. You should move your logic into your action. This is just a guess without more details to the question. Here is an example:

```js
const myAction = (stuff) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let oldLength = getState().myState.stuff.length
    dispatch(doStuffToStuff(stuff))
    let newLength = getState().myState.stuff.length
    dispatch(moreStuffToLength(newLength))
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote this thing but not for a component but as a helper method for an action .That is an action called this helper const myaction to get things done.Is it something related to batched dispatches that lead to a wrong interpretation of the state?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the issue was resolved .After every dispatch if the state changes it is required to access the new state by ysing getState() I wasn't doing that .